# Angular 4 Lazy Loading without using Routing process

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ondemand

Is it possible to do Lazy Loading with Angular 4 without using Routing process? 
Just with code on demand, without edit URL.

We have to developp Web Application, with some of modules, loaded when user want to use a feature, or when user have habilitation to use it.

We have many module (about 20), so use URL to define state of application for loading X module does not seem relevant.

Comment: Can you provide an example on what do you mean with "code on demand"?

Comment: Hello Crash, for example, when a user click on button, I would like to load Widget with lazy loading process.

The code seems like this : 

public buttonClickHandler(event:any):void
{
 import("MyWidgetModule").then(myModule.render());
}

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if you have a solution to your question I have the same problem